# Log into site with username and password in a requests session

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have written the following code in Python to log into a particular site, but have not yet been successful in doing so. Each time I enter the correct credentials, log in appears not to have happened.

My code runs as follows:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USERNAME = "abe"
PASSWORD = input("password: ")
LOGIN_URL = <login_page_url>
URL = <page_available_after_logging_in>
AUTH_TOKEN_NAME = 'authenticity_token'

session_requests = requests.session()

# Get authenticity token
result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name=AUTH_TOKEN_NAME]/@value")))[0]

# Create payload
payload = {
    "name": USERNAME, 
    "user_pin": PASSWORD, 
    "authenticity_token": authenticity_token
}

# Perform login
result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers=dict(referer=LOGIN_URL))

# Check if logged in:
r2 = session_requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, 'html.parser')
logged_in = soup.find_all('span', string='A string that exists if logged in')
if logged_in:
    print('logged in successfully')
else:
    print('login failed')
```

When I check if I am logged in, I expect to see a particular string that I know should be there, and without fail, it never seems to appear. Some ideas I have about what the issue might be:

1. Some issue to do with cookies. Am I carrying those over properly by using the `session_requests` variable or have I made some mistake there?
2. Need to wait before attempting to access the next page. Is there a need to wait in between the `.post` call and accessing the other `URL` or should that work as is? I don't know how long the page would need to reload.
3. Authentication token. Could there be an issue in obtaining this token? I believe I am getting the one I want with that `lxml` code, but maybe that's incorrect as well.

Comment: Can you provide a curl example that works, or similar? I can't really figure out what you should be doing, if you don't know or provide not url to test against. Usually HTTP authentication is done via authentication header, rather than a token in the body.

Comment: What is the authentication header method?

Comment: Use a monitor like Telerik Fiddler to spy on your browser while you open the login page and then log in - then a) use a requests session so cookie are handled automatically, and b) replicate the headers of the login in your code.

Comment: Rather than fiddler, just have your network tab open in your browser, you can inspect the request it makes there.

Comment: Can you share the login url?

Comment: This too specific to the API you're using, everyone does authentication slightly different, you either provide the links to the API you're using and have a long shot at someone figuring it out for you, or go figure it and come up with a proper question about it. This question is invalid from my point a view.